# How to freeze text from moving in console.log

Tags: javascript

So I have a simple console.log script that prints this
[image]

Now when I add a letter is moves [image]

any way to freeze it please?
code [image]

Comment: Remove the space before/after the new letter.

Comment: The console is for debugging, not general purpose output. Why are you trying to do fancy formatting there?

Comment: @Barmar
updated it sorry

Comment: Why not init Cell2 to 9 with a space rather than empty string? That would keep the whole thing aligned

Comment: @AnthonyGarcia-Labiad because them will be filled later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably make more sense to make all of your cells contain a space character if they are "empty". Take a look here:

```js
var Cell_1 = "a";
var Cell_2 = " ";
var Cell_3 = " ";
var Cell_4 = " ";
var Cell_5 = " ";
var Cell_6 = " ";
var Cell_7 = " ";
var Cell_8 = " ";
var Cell_9 = " ";

console.log(
Cell_1 + "|" + Cell_2 + "|" + Cell_3 + "\n" +
Cell_5 + "|" + Cell_6 + "|" + Cell_6 + "\n" +
Cell_7 + "|" + Cell_8 + "|" + Cell_9 + "\n" +
)
```

This way all of your variables are the same width - one character.

For future reference, here's some code that would probably look a bit nicer:

```js
// This is called a 2d array: essentially an array containing other arrays.
// Its good for storing grids or tables of information.
var cells = [
  ['a', ' ', ' '],
  [' ', ' ', ' '],
  [' ', ' ', ' ']
]

// This uses Array.reduce() to generate the string.
// Google it once you feel more confident :)
console.log(
  cells.reduce(
    (totalString, currentRow) => totalString + currentRow.join('|') + '\n',
    ''
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't very clear but I am assuming that you want to keep a grid aligned, the grid having multiple cells that can contain a character or not.

The problem is that the empty cells are initialised to `""` (empty string) which is of size 0, but when a character is set the size will be 1, so it will shift all the following cells of 1.

An easy solution is to use a `" "` (space) for the empty cell instead of a `""`. As a result the size of a cell will always be 1 and the whole grid won't be shifted.